# How large is the city of Elturel?

Tags: lore, forgotten-realms, maps

The question is how long is the perimeter of Elturel's city limits, defined by the city walls and the river Chiontar.

I currently have one player who got himself a mount with a 120' flight speed and I'd need to know how long he'd take to fly around it. Unfortunately all maps I can get my hands on do not seem to have a scale.

In case anybody is wondering: yes, we're in the finale of *Descent into Avernus*.

Comment: I didn't notice somebody added the "dnd-5e" and the specific adventure tags. I considered them and avoided them to keep the answer independent of the adventure and consider material from earlier editions perfectly valid.

Comment: Picking the accepted answer was tough. In the end the better source is what should count for most in a question like this one, so I chose accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the size of the city (particularly the city walls) haven't changed since 2nd Edition, I pulled up the Forgotten Realms Interactive Atlas.

[image: Elturel]

It does come with a distance measuring tool, but only for straight lines (no polygons/paths). And then there's extra error depending on [how you measure the coastline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) or just the point where you place one click and the next one. On the plus side, it's vector based without perspective, so the error should be less than those from raster images. All in all the error should be reasonably low.

My measurements come up at a perimeter of 9,543 feet.

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a FR interactive atlas! How official is it? Is there a link available?

Comment: @Rad80 it's [quite official](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Interactive_Atlas), but no longer supported. [Petitions were signed](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119035815/http://www.profantasy.com/petition/default.asp), but to no avail. Your best bet is to catch it on Ebay, but they sell for quite a few GPs.

Answer (score 15):

#### The perimeter is around 12,000 feet.

Using the [full size map](https://www.dndbeyond.com/attachments/6/325/huyub-map-2-1.jpg) (available for free at DDB), I based this off of the description of the bridges between the two sections of Elturel:

> When the characters approach either bridge, they can make out the initial details of the rift and can see the guards blocking the path. Read the following to set the scene:
>
> > A rift in the earth divides Elturel into two sections. The riotous din of the battle taking place far below the city is louder here, echoing up and through the jagged open chasm.
> >
> > **A bridge twenty feet wide and more than a hundred feet long spans the chasm.** Holy runes etched into the stonework of the bridge indicate that the structure has been consecrated in the name of Torm, god of courage and self-sacrifice. Six infernal creatures stand guard at the center of the bridge, scanning in all directions.

The Torm's Blade bridge runs parallel to the top and bottom edges of the map, so I opened the map in MS Paint and counted the pixels, getting 15-17 pixels, depending on how you interpret which pixels are bridge and which are the bridge's boundary. At 20 feet wide and 16 pixels, that gives us 5 feet = 4 pixels.

So here is the map with a scale added in the bottom center (in multiples of 120 feet):

[image]

I then recorded the coordinates for a set of points around the city's perimeter and calculated the distance around the city, which came out to 12,275 feet. With a 120 foot flying speed, this makes for a roughly 10 minute lap around the perimeter of the city if you don't allow free use of the Dash action (see chase rules in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*).

Comment: I upvoted this, it might be useful to confirm that each section of the scale is 125 ft, not 100 as one would have expected, as there are only 4 section?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin That is correct, though I can provide a different scale upon request.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin try it now.

Comment: Very nice and clear

Comment: It may be of note that highly stylized maps like the one here tend to not have uniform scale. Especially points of interest may be exaggerated. So anything from 10,000 to 50,000 could be reasonable.

Comment: You did a great job, but this map is intrinsecally less precise. The error margin in measuring 16 pixel with uncertain boundaries is relevant. Add to that the considerations on whether the artist really thought about the official bridge width when making the image (not likely) and I have to recognize that @roflo's answer just has the better source seeing that this map obviously comes straight from the old map from 2e. Thank you for your great work, I think you really did the best estimate possible with 5e material.